# Regression - significance of a variable

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have been running a linear regression, and one of the variables was a discrete variable (3 categories), decoded into three binary variables.

I ran the regression in Stata. The first of those three variables was omitted, the other two were tested for significance (a ttest I assume); the resulting p-values were strikingly different: $0.682$ and $0.049$. Before removing entirely that discrete variable from regression, I decided to test those two binary variables for joint significance; the result was a p-value of $0.0746$, which would indicate that for a significance level of, say $\alpha=0.1$ (still reasonable, I guess), we reject the null asserting joint insignificance.

I know that in general, there is no "recipe" which would directly tell us which variables are significant, and which should not be kept. Nonetheless, in this case, is there any sound rationale for keeping the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the variable was omitted because you fell into something called the "dummy variable trap."  Google it.

Second, whether or not to keep a non-significant variable depends on your problem.  In some cases, you need to control for things that won't necessarily be significant in order to lend your estimates causal interpretation.  In pure prediction, you drop variables based on model selection criteria such as AIC.  Without more info on your goals, nobody can tell you what you need to do here.